# 1-Wire Interfaces

Tags: 1-wire

I am wondering about the experience of users in this site with the [1-Wire](http://www.maximintegrated.com/products/1-wire/) interface
as far as reliability in communications and ease of use.

From my perspective, the main issue I see is the lack of native 1-Wire modules in microcontrollers, which means it has to be done in software with some timers. I've even used it a little bit with FPGAs using Maxim's own [1-Wire FPGA syntesizable module](http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/119), but the results were pretty horrendous since it didn't work and I ended up using a software solution (which requires careful timing). Perhaps using an actual timer with capture/compare would have made a few things easier.

So, from your perspective:

1) Has it been reliable and useful in your projects?

2) How did you implement the communications interface?

Any tips/tricks that make it easy to use would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A bit more context would help.  What kind of instrument are you designing?  What kind of 1-wire peripheral(s) are you considering?

Comment: I was planning on adding a few temp sensors to a board. I2C is easy, but some interesting devices come in 1-Wire and I've had bad experiences with it before.

Comment: 1-Wire is easy to implement, and doesn't hog a lot of pins if that is a concern. It has it's limitations, just like anything else. I don't agree that you should avoid it if possible. It simply depends on the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had bad experience with 1-wire too.  1-wire performs poorly in presence of EMI**.

IMHO, the only reasonable niche for 1-wire are applications where every wire and connector pin is very precious, and slow communication rate is acceptable.  These are usually low cost and high volume products, for example: disposable medical applicators, printer ink cartridges, meshes of wired peripherals in non-trivial numbers.

Generally, I don't see a point for choosing 1-wire over I<sup>2</sup>C, when peripherals are on the same PCB as the master.  Wiring is affordable within PCB.

There are [I<sup>2</sup>C to 1-wire bridge](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2482-100.pdf) ICs, which can take low-level burden from the main controller.

** I<sup>2</sup>C is not the most EMI-resilient bus either.  Still, I<sup>2</sup>C works better than 1-wire in presence of EMI.

Comment: I think your post sums it up as "Avoid it if possible" which was my feeling as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've only once did anything with a 1-wire bus, and that was to build a test jig that connected to existing equipment that contained a 1-wire EEPROM.  This jig had to, among other things, read and write the EEPROM.

Everything just worked as I remember it.  Of course before writing any code I carefully read the Dallas 1-wire spec and the datasheet for the particular part.  After understanding the 1-wire bus, the firmware layers to implement the protocol become apparent.  Again, there were no surprises, and everything worked as expected.  I even ended up with host code that could enumerate all the devices on the 1-wire bus.

I wouldn't go long distances with 1-wire, but it seems to work well for what it is intended for.  As with most things, **read the datasheet**, and the rest is just implementation.

### Added:

In response to a comment below, I went back and checked how exactly the timing was implemented in this one case.  The processor was a PIC 18 and timing was done by turning off interrupts temporarily and executing a controlled number of instructions.  In this particular system, there was plenty of processing power and interrupts being off occasionally for a few 10s of microseconds was acceptable.  That may not be the case with other implementations.  Each case should be thought about separately.

Here are the critical routines for reading and writing individual bits.  Only these two routines and the bus reset routine turned off interrupts and did critical timing.  Everything was else firmware above this low level layer, like reading and writing whole bytes and enumerating the bus devices.

```
;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Subroutine WIRE1_WRBIT
;
;   Write a single bit to the 1-wire bus.  The bit value is taken from the low
;   bit of REG0.  All FSRs are preserved.
;
         glbsub  wire1_wrbit, noregs

         intr_off            ;temp disable interrupts for accurate timing
         bus_low             ;start the write slot
         btfsc   reg0, 0     ;bit value is 0 ?
         jump    write1      ;bit value is 1
;
;   The bit value is 0.
;
         wait_us 62, 3       ;hold bus low for 62 us
         bus_high
         intr_on             ;re-enable interrupts
         wait_us 2, 6        ;leave high for at least 2 us
         jump    write_leave
;
;   The bit value is 1.
;
write1   unbank
         wait_us 2, 4        ;hold low for 2 us
         bus_high
         intr_on             ;re-enable interrupts
         wait_us 60, 4       ;leave high rest of bit time

write_leave unbank           ;common exit point
         leaverest

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Subroutine WIRE1_RDBIT
;
;   Read a single bit from the 1-wire bus.  The bit value is returned in the
;   high bit of REG0.  The remaining bits of REG0 are not altered.  All FSRs are
;   preserved.
;
         glbsub  wire1_rdbit, noregs

         intr_off            ;temp disable interrupts for accurate timing

         bus_low             ;start the read slot
         wait_us 2, 1        ;hold bus low for 2 us to indicate read slot
         bus_high            ;let the device drive the bus

         wait_us 10, 2       ;wait for reply from device to be stable
         bcf     reg0, 7     ;init returned data bit to 0
         dbankif wire1_reg
         btfsc   wire1_reg, wire1_bit ;data bit is 0 ?
         bsf     reg0, 7     ;no, set returned bit to 1

         intr_on             ;re-enable interrupts
         wait_us 50, 4       ;guarantee minimum bit time of 62 us

         leaverest
```

Comment: I agree that it's down to the implementation. Do you remember how you implemented it? Was is all software toggling, timers?

Comment: @Gustavo: See addition to answer.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - That was exactly my reaction too.